# GRASS GIS add-on error

Tags: grass-gis, error, add-ons, grass-7.8

I installed i.ann.maskrcnn in GRASS GIS 7.8.3
but, I got error message in the picture.

[image]

How can I download metadata file about this tool?

Comment: Please edit and add your operating system. Note that this is an (undesired - to be fixed) warning and not an error - does it actually work?

Comment: Not actually.. tool is shown in the list, but not activated.

Comment: I have notified the author about it, hope they take a look. If not, please open a bug report at https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/issues